# Win32 api format message with node-ffi

Tags: winapi, kernel32, node-ffi

I am trying to use node-ffi to interface with the win32 api FormatMessageA however I cannot seem to get the out lpBuffer parameter, here is a snippet of code to show what I have tried

```
   'use strict';

   const ref = require('ref');
   const ffi = require('ffi');

   const Kernel32 = ffi.Library('Kernel32.dll', {
       FormatMessageA: ['ulong', [
           'ulong', //flags 
           'void *', 
           'ulong', //status number
           'ulong', //language 
           'uchar *',
           'ulong',
           'void *'
       ]]
   });


   const FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = 0x1000;
   const FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER = 0x100;
   const FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS = 0x200;

   const lpBuffer = ref.alloc('uchar *'); 

   const result = Kernel32.FormatMessageA(
       FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
       null, 
       0x80090300, //error code
       0,
       lpBuffer,
       0, 
       null
   );

   console.log(result); //prints 57 bytes
```

I know function is successful as it returns 57 however I cannot get lpBuffer value which contains the error string I require.

Comment: From [MSDN: FormatMessage function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx): "_The `lpBuffer` parameter is a pointer to an `LPTSTR`; you must cast the pointer to an `LPTSTR` (for example, `(LPTSTR)&lpBuffer`)._" The 2nd example (at the end of the same page) illustrates how to use `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER `.

Comment: This is using javascript using ffi to create data type? I can do this in c no problem, just not via a foreign interface

Comment: Yes, I know that the example is for _C_ while you're using _JS_ (that I have absolutely no knowledge of), but (assuming that your code is correct), the documentation tells me that `lpBuffer` should be `ref.alloc('uchar **')` (don't know if that makes any sense in _JS_).

Comment: Yes it does, didn't see that. I will check and if you want to supply an answer I will accept if it works.

Comment: That worked a charm, many thanks!  If you write an answer I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my 1<sup>st</sup> comment, according to [[MSDN] `FormatMessage` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx):

- `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` description:

  > The `lpBuffer` parameter is a **pointer** to an `LPTSTR`; you must cast the pointer to an `LPTSTR` (for example, `(LPTSTR)&lpBuffer)`.
- The (2<sup>nd</sup>) example at the bottom of the page:

  ```
  // Some code (not relevant for this problem)
  LPWSTR pBuffer = NULL;
  // Some more code (still not relevant)
  FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING |
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
                pMessage, 
                0,
                0,
                (LPWSTR)&pBuffer,
  // The rest of the code (not relevant)
  ```

when the `dwFlags` argument is composed of `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`, the function expects that the `lpBuffer` argument which is a `LPTSTR` (pointer to `TCHAR`), to actually be a **pointer** to `LPTSTR` (double pointer to `TCHAR`) *cast* ed to `LPTSTR`.

That, translated in *JS* (that I have no experience with), would mean:

```
const lpBuffer = ref.alloc('uchar **');
```

**Note**: according to the same page, the buffer should be freed using `LocalFree` when it's no longer needed (makes sense, since `FormatMessage` allocates memory for it - that's why it requires to be a double pointer). Again, don't know how this would translate in *JS* (what I do know is that `LocalFree` should be called on an `uchar *`(dereferenced) buffer, not directly on `lpBuffer`).

Comment: Yes I had to write a javascript interface to GetProcessHeap and HeapFree to allow me to free buffer from javascript to prevent memory leak.